# Chart.js Tooltip over the line not only over points

Tags: chart.js, tooltip

I have a line chart in chart.js. Now I would like to have a tooltip, when I hover over the line not just when i hover over a point.
The tooltip should then be displayed at the position of the mouse.
Is this somehow possible?

I have tried all interaction.mode options, but non of them have this behavior.

Thank You

Answer (score 5):

You can use the croshair plugin for this if you are still using v2 of the lib: https://chartjs-plugin-crosshair.netlify.app/

Live example:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

function generateDataset(shift, label, color) {

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  let data = [];
  let index = 0;

  while (index < 5) {
    data.push({
      x: index,
      y: getRandomInt(10, 40)
    });
    index++;
  }

  var dataset = {
    backgroundColor: color,
    borderColor: color,
    showLine: true,
    fill: false,
    pointRadius: 2,
    label: label,
    data: data,
    lineTension: 0,
    interpolate: true,
    xAxisID: 'x-axis-0'
  };
  return dataset;
}

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    datasets: [
      generateDataset(0, "A", "red"),
      generateDataset(1, "B", "green")
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'bottom',
        id: 'x-axis-0',
        ticks: {
          source: 'labels'
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: "interpolate",
      intersect: false,
      callbacks: {
        title: function(a, d) {
          // return a[0].xLabel.toFixed(2);
          return a[0].xLabel;
        },
        label: function(i, d) {
          return (
            d.datasets[i.datasetIndex].label + ": " + i.yLabel.toFixed(2)
          );
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      crosshair: {
        line: {
          // Add alpha chanel so line becomes transparant so you dont see it
          color: '#ffffff00',
        },
        sync: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="myChartDiv">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/chartjs-plugin-crosshair@1.1.6/dist/chartjs-plugin-crosshair.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you are using V3 of the lib you will need to use a custom own plugin

Example:

```js
// Options for the indicators
const indicatorOptions = {
  radius: 4, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red', backgroundColor: 'transparent'
};

// Override getLabelAndValue to return the interpolated value
const getLabelAndValue = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.getLabelAndValue;
Chart.controllers.line.prototype.getLabelAndValue = function(index) {
  if (index === -1) {
    const meta = this.getMeta();
    const pt = meta._pt;
    const vScale = meta.vScale;
    return {
      label: 'interpolated',
      value: vScale.getValueForPixel(pt.y)
    };
  }
  return getLabelAndValue.call(this, index);
}

// The interaction mode
Chart.Interaction.modes.interpolate = function (chart, e, option) {
  const x = e.x;
  const items = [];
  const metas = chart.getSortedVisibleDatasetMetas();
  for (let i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
    const meta = metas[i];
    const pt = meta.dataset.interpolate({ x }, "x");
    if (pt) {
      const element = new Chart.elements.PointElement({...pt, options: {...indicatorOptions}});
      meta._pt = element;
      items.push({element, index: -1, datasetIndex: meta.index });
    } else {
      meta._pt = null;
    }
  }
  return items;
};

// Plugin to draw the indicators
Chart.register({
  id: 'indicators',
  afterDraw(chart) {
    const metas = chart.getSortedVisibleDatasetMetas();
    for (let i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
      const meta = metas[i];
      if (meta._pt) {
        meta._pt.draw(chart.ctx);
      }
    }    
  },
  afterEvent(chart, args) {
    if (args.event.type === 'mouseout') {
      const metas = chart.getSortedVisibleDatasetMetas();
      for (let i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
        metas[i]._pt = null;
      }
      args.changed = true;
    }
  }
})

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
      {
        fill: true,
        label: "My First dataset",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(132, 0, 0, 1)",
        borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
        data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
      },
      {
        data: [30, 40, 50],
        label: 'My Second Dataset',
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: "lightgreen",
        borderColor: "green"
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    interaction: {
      mode: "interpolate",
      intersect: false,
      axis: "x"
    },
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        position: 'nearest',
        displayColors: false,
      }
    }
  },
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Interpolating line values</h1>
<div class="myChartDiv">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You, this goes in the right direction. One detail: I use chart.js V3 so I tried your plugin. Now when I have several datasets like in your example, the tooltip is shown between them. My goal is to show it on that line, where my mouse is over, additionally it should only be displayed when I am over or near the line. Is this possible?

Comment: You can set `position: 'nearest'` in the tooltip options, see updated answer

Comment: I am sorry, but i have one more question. I use a stepped line (stepped: true) with this option the tooltips are always one step ahead. I think it is a bug in meta.dataset.interpolate. Do you know a fix or workaround for it?